# Android SQLite DatabaseHandler

Tags: android, sqlite

Trying out this SQLite db at this link:

[Android Hive SQLite](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

With the last line of the following code snippet, at the moment, I'm just trying to get a number in to the num variable:

```
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

    /**
     * CRUD Operations
     * */
    // Inserting Contacts
    Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting .."); 
    db.addContact(new Contact(5, "Bill", "9100000000"));        
    db.addContact(new Contact(6, "Fred", "9199999999"));
    db.addContact(new Contact(7, "George", "9522222222"));
    db.addContact(new Contact(8, "Jack", "9533333333"));

    num = db.getContactsCount();
```

This is the method from the DatabaseHandler:

```
// Getting contacts Count
public int getContactsCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();

    // return count
    return cursor.getCount();
}
```

The LogCat is saying **'attempt to re-open an already-closed object'**. What would generally cause this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is here in `getContactsCount()` method.

```
 cursor.close();

 // return count
 return cursor.getCount();
```

you have closed the cursor and after that you are querying it for count. To make it work , change your code like this

```
int count = cursor.getCount();
cursor.close();
return count;
```

Comment: Oh man, that was a classic rookie mistake. How could I??? Working fine now Waqar.

Answer (score 0):

I think @Waqar Ahmed is right.

Try this:

```
public int getContactsCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    int contactsCount = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();

    // return count
    return contactsCount;
}
```